# How to auto select all friends to invite to my facebook app

Tags: facebook

I have developed an app but to make this app to reach out my friends i want to add " Invite friends to continue to app" as done in this app

https://apps.facebook.com/hulk_game/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=1_0

when you click play button the invite friends pops up and when you click on cancle button then  alert message comes out.

Comment: Don't you think it is just not fair?

Comment: if you could help me out with code then  it would be more helpful to me.

Comment: but don't you think it is unfair, that user need to "sell" all his friends to you to use your app?

Comment: After working so hard for a app if i dont get the desired amount of visitors then it is waste to work so hard. I am not a professional coder or designer but this could be just a motivation for me if i get visitors to my app.

Comment: If you don't get desired amount of visitors - it means that visitors didn't like or don't need your app. Was you required to send spam to all your friends to be able to post the question here on SO? No.

Comment: ok if you could let me know the code for only auto selecting the friends by itself not by clicking and selecting each friend one by one ...

Comment: No possible using the standard requests dialog. But the documentation has an example on how to build a custom friend selector, wherein you’re free to implement that feature yourself. (Although requests are limited to going out to 50 friends max, IIRC.) And I have to agree with the previous comments … if you think your _“hard work”_ for your app doesn’t get enough recognition by your app behaving in a decent matter … then probably you haven’t worked __hard enough__ on it yet.

Answer (score 1):

a picture worth more than words

[image: facebook policies]

Answer (score 0):

It's against Facebook Terms to select "all" friends by default. The user should have control over who they want to select. In addition, Sharing should not be forced / incentivized on a user. If your app / content is good, it will be shared naturally - not forced sharing as you are attempting to do.